# Splash no funciona fluidamente - Xamarin.Android C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin

Tengo el MainActivity configurado para hacer un splash (animación o logo antes de iniciar la aplicación), y me funciona, el problema es que antes de cargar el layout del splash "Main.axml" se queda como 3 segundos mostrando una pantalla negra con solo la etiqueta de la app ("***Hola Mundo***") y hasta luego el "Main.axml", entonces pierde el efecto deseado.

Alguna idea para revisar o mejorar.

Comparto código:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
        
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            try
            {
                RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle); 
                base.OnCreate(bundle);                     
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber=Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7);
                ShowToast("Error en linea: " + LineErrorNumber + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message, false);
            }
        }

protected override void OnResume()
        {
            try
            {                
                base.OnResume();
                Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
                startupWork.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7);
                ShowToast("Error en linea: " + LineErrorNumber + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message, false);
            }
        }
    
    async void SimulateStartup()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000); //5 segundos mostrando el splash deseado.                
            
            var Intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(LoginAux));
            StartActivity(Intent);
            
            Intent.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            string LineErrorNumber = Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7);
            ShowToast("Error en linea: " + LineErrorNumber + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message, false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar El splash se crea otro `Activity`, y tenes que pasarle 3 propiedades en el Decorador, " `MainLancher= true`" es para que sea este el principal `Activity`, "`NoHistory = true`" es para que no quede en la pila de navegacion este activity y por ultimo el `Theme` que lleva tu activity que contiene la imagen del splash.

Y el ultimo paso, en tu `activity` Principal que seria `mainActivity`, colocas `MainLancher = false`;

```
[Activity(Label = "Mi App", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/ThemeSplash")]
    public class Splash : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            StartActivity( new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));

            // Create your application here
        }
    }
```